# Output a javascript string to a page using C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Fairly new to C# and am sure there is an easy to solution to this but am just not seeing it.

Basically I have some javascript stored in a variable that I would only like to output to the page if a certain condition has been met.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<%= conditionMet ? rawJavascriptString : "" %>
```

This however won't work, I'm sure this is a simple one but would appreciate any help. So the question is how can I render a script on the response if some condition is met and omit it otherwise?

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: What view engine are you using for that page?

Comment: Are `conditionMet` and `rawJavascriptString` both public vars?

Comment: You don't need Response.Write()?

Comment: yeah both are public variables. I can get the form to recognise whether or not the condition has been met and out put meaningless strings. I just can't the get the value of the Javascript to appear.

Comment: Define 'won't work' and when you says variable do you mean a c# var or a JS var? Can we see the c# where you define `conditionMet` and `rawJavascriptString`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of registering the script in the ASPX directly, have a look at the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It provides methods to output JavaScript (or similar client script blocks) programmatically. You can check your condition and use it in the CodeBehind file (e.g. in the Page_Load-event) to output the script:

```
if (conditionMet) 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
            "MyKey", 
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Test');</script>", false);
```

Especially the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods might be useful. In order to uniquely identify a script, you provide a type and a key. These can also be used to remove or replace the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like

```
<span id="content"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var rawJavascriptString = 'whatever'
    var serverSideValue = '<%= conditionMet %>';

    if (serverSideValue ) {
        $("span#content").text(rawJavascriptString);
    }

</script>
```

Basically you can get the value of the server-side variable outputted to a JavaScript variable, then use that variable to work out what to set the content to.

Naturally I don't know what your HTML looks like, but the above is a simply example which you can work to suite your needs. Also, overall, I think it's a bit cleaner, but that's a subjective opinion :)